# How to handle large number of redirects in Node/Vue app?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, redirect, vue-router

I am working on migrating an existing app to a new tech stack that uses Node and MongoDB on the backend and Vue on the frontend. I have a fairly large number of pages that will need to be redirected to new URLs (over 50). I know I can do something like this in the frontend:

```
const appRouter = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/a', redirect: '/a2' },
    { path: '/b', redirect: '/b2' },
    { path: '/c', redirect: '/c2' },
  ]
});
```

However it doesn't strike me as particularly elegant. I could see keeping the redirects in another file and importing them to keep my router file neater, but that seems like just a formatting benefit.

I'm wondering how other people handle a large number of redirects in Vue? Would this be better to do at the server-level with Node?

Comment: uses regex match will be one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a fairly large number of pages that will need to be redirected to new URLs

When we talk about *redirecting* a Uniform Resource Locator (URL) in the context of a Single Page Application (SPA) like Vue with Vue Router, hosted by a web server like Node.js, we might mean one of two things:

1. we've changed the route of a view within our Vue SPA
2. we've changed the location of our SPA (the *resource*) from one location to another.

To determine which kind of redirect you need to do, we can examine how the URL will change. URLs are made up of these components:

`scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`

By default, [Vue Router uses the `#fragment` (hash) portion of the URL](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#mode) to change views, so if this changes then we should redirect using [Alias or Redirect](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/docs/en/essentials/redirect-and-alias.md).

If any other portion of the URL changes, we should have Node.js return an HTTP status code for redirect, like `301 Moved Permanently` or `302 Moved Temporarily`.

Comment: Good point! It's the path that's changing, so I'm going with a 301 redirect on the Node server.

Answer (score 2):

If boilerplate is the problem, you can use something like:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/([abc])', redirect: to => {
        returect to.path + '2'; // to.path will be like '/a'
    }}
  ]
})
```

Notice that the part inside `()` is a regex that can be customized.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the solution from @acdcjunior is good enough, but sometimes you may prefer hooking `beforeRouteUpdate` to implement the redirect.

You can check [vue-router: dynamic Routing](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) for more details.

Below is one simple sample is from the official document:

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    if ( to.match(new RegExp('your_regex_expression'))) {
        next('redirect_url')
    } else {
        // default
        next()
    }
  }
}
```

Or in main.js by using [global guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html):

```
import router from './router'

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if ( to.match(new RegExp('your_regex_expression'))) {
        next('redirect_url')
    } else {
        // default
        next()
    }
})
```